# creating a data base with peewee execute_sql self.commit()

Tags: python, peewee

I used some very simple code to create a database with peewee, I am new to using python ORMs so I can't really tell why I'm getting a whole bunch of errors. 
What this code does is: First I create a database 'diary.db'
the data types used are entries, which is a Text Field, and date, which is a DateTimeField. I created some functions: 'initialize' to run basic commands and initialize the database, 'menu_loop' that will show a menu that works with an infinite loop and may call the function 'add_entry' that adds new entries to the database.

Heres the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import OrderedDict
from peewee import *
import datetime
import sys

db = SqliteDatabase('diary.db')

class Diary(Model):
    entries = TextField()
    date = DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    class Meta:
        database = db

def initialize():
    """initializes the database"""
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Diary], safe = True)
#end of initialize

def menu_loop():
    """show menu"""
    choice = 0
    while choice != 2:
        print("Enter '2' to quit")
        print('1) to add an entry')
        choice = input()
        if choice == 1:
            add_entry()
#end of menu_loop

def add_entry():
    """add an entry"""
    print("Enter your entry, press ctrl+d when done")
    data = sys.stdin.read().strip()
    if data:
        while(True):
            option = input('\nSave entry?[1 = yes 0 = no] ')
            if option == 1:
                Diary.create(content=data)
                print ("Saved sucessfully!")
            if option == 0:
                print ("Program exited")
                break;
#end of add_entry

if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize()
    menu_loop()
```

and the error log

```
Enter '2' to quit
1) to add an entry
1
Enter your entry, press ctrl+d when done
this is my new entry
hello world^D
Save entry?[1 = yes 0 = no] 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ispythonsmart.py", line 50, in <module>
    menu_loop()
  File "ispythonsmart.py", line 30, in menu_loop
    add_entry()
  File "ispythonsmart.py", line 41, in add_entry
    Diary.create(content=data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4494, in create
    inst.save(force_insert=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4680, in save
    pk_from_cursor = self.insert(**field_dict).execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3213, in execute
    cursor = self._execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2628, in _execute
    return self.database.execute_sql(sql, params, self.require_commit)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3461, in execute_sql
    self.commit()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3285, in __exit__
    reraise(new_type, new_type(*exc_args), traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3454, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: diary.entries
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set entries to `null=True` or use a default value for entries:

```
class Diary(Model):
    entries = TextField(null=True)
```

Output:

```
Enter '2' to quit
1) to add an entry
1
Enter your entry, press ctrl+d when done
foobar

Save entry?[1 = yes 0 = no] 1
Saved successfully!
```

You want to see `"entries" TEXT` in the db not `"entries" TEXT NOT NULL`. If a column is set to `NOT NULL` you must insert a value or you will get an integrity error, an alternative is to give a default value for the column i.e  `TextField(default="foo")`. On a sidenote you have `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as your shebang but your code is written for python 2 so you may want to correct that.